# onClick event on a button fires even if the button is not clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an event listener to a button, here is the code I used:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('loginButton').onClick = logInToPod();
}
```

The problem is that for some reason the `logInToPod()`function gets called as soon as the page loads without clicking the button, while the code I wrote should just add the event listener, and not call the function until I click the button, right?

I'm using webpack, I don't know if that matters or is causing this.

Comment: Did you mean `.onclick`? Also make sure to prevent the default action inside the callback function, or return false. Also remove the parenthesis from `logInToPod()`, you're calling the function immediately.

Comment: I tried onclick instead of onClick, but the behavior is still the same unfortunately

Comment: Please read the second part of the comment?

Comment: Make sure you've saved your source and clear all your browser cache when you edit code.  (I sometimes add another alert to ensure I'm running the code I expect)

Comment: Voting to close as a typo - `onclick` not `onClick` - the latter is how it's done in React not in normal JS.

Comment: It was a cache problem, removing the parentheses as @evolutionxbox said worked, it just didn't update on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 major issues:

1. `onClick` should be `onclick`;
2. `logInToPod()` should be `logInToPod`.

So I would suggest to modify your code like:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('loginButton').onclick = logInToPod;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/t02mcuop/2/) a JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is coming because you are calling logInToPod function directly with parenthesis, which means it will be evaluated at the same thime as the `window.load` will get executed.
You should call it via a pointer, as I had listed below

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('loginButton').onclick = logInToPod;
}

function logInToPod()
{
    alert("You have clicked me!");
}
```

```html
<button id="loginButton">Click me to alert</button>
```

Here `logIntoPod` is a pointer that is pointing to the function and it will be evaluated with the click event will be triggered.